# Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code and not starting

Tags: mysql, linux

I found this same issue other people are facing, I tried their solutions, unfortunately nothing worked.

If I try `service mysql start` I get this error

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

When I run this `/etc/init.d/mysql start`
I get

```
Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
failed!

What is the solution? I have 5gb space left out of 25 so space seems available.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
```

and then start your mysql server with

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Check the server status with

```
sudo service mysql status
```